# Polymer. How to unit test filter function

Tags: unit-testing, polymer

I'm using Polymer. I have simple filter function:

```
_queryFilter: function(query){
  return function(field){
    if (!query) return true;
    if (!field) return false;
    return (field.name && ~field.name.indexOf(query));
  };
}
```

This is element:

```
  <input type="text" placeholder="filter" value="{{filterVal::input}}">

  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{fields}}" filter="{{_queryFilter(filterVal)}}">
    {{item.name}}
  </template>
```

I want to unit test it this way: give fixtured 'fields' array, give 'query' and check the output which function will give. How to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web Component Tester (WCT) is used for testing Polymer elements. To test your template repeater's filter function, there are two relevant points from the [Polymer Testing Guide](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/tools/tests.html):

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/tools/tests.html#test-fixtures

> To use a test fixture:
>
> - Define the test fixture template and give it an ID.
> - Define a variable in your test script to reference the template.
> - Instantiate a new instance of the fixture in your setup() method.

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/tools/tests.html#test-dom-mutations

> Always wrap your test in `flush` if your element template contains a template repeater (`dom-repeat`) or conditional template (`dom-if`), or if your test involves a local DOM mutation. Polymer lazily performs these operations in some cases for performance. `flush` ensures that asynchronous changes have taken place. The test function should take one argument, `done`, to indicate that it is asynchronous, and it should call `done()` at the end of `flush`.

Given:

```
<dom-module id="x-foo">
  <template>
    <input type="text" placeholder="filter" value="{{filterVal::input}}">
    <ul>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{fields}}" filter="{{_queryFilter(filterVal)}}">
        <li class="name">{{item.name}}</li>
      </template>
    </ul>
  </template>
  <script>...</script>
</dom-module>
```

Your `test.html` would look something like this:

```
<test-fixture id="basic">
  <template>
     <x-foo></x-foo>
  </template>
</test-fixture>

<script>
  suite('<x-foo>', function() {
    var list, listItems;

    setup(function() {
      list = fixture('basic');
    });

    test('filters fields', function(done) {
      list.fields = [
        {name: 'foo'},
        {name: 'bar'}
      ];
      list.filterVal = 'f';

      flush(function() {
        listItems = Polymer.dom(list.root).querySelectorAll('li.name');
        assert.equal(1, listItems.length);
        assert.equal('foo', listItems[0].textContent);
        done();
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Your unit test for `_queryFilter()` could look like this:

```
test('_queryFilter() performs filtering', function() {
  var filter = list._queryFilter('o');
  var passedFilter = function(field) {
    return filter(field) !== 0;
  };
  assert.isTrue(passedFilter({name: 'foo'}));
  assert.isFalse(passedFilter({name: 'bar'}));
});
```

---

I recommend playing around with [Polymer Starter Kit](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit), which already includes a couple test elements scaffolded with WCT (e.g., [`app/test/my-list-basic.html`](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/blob/0c3c065/app/test/my-list-basic.html)).